# How symfony's asset url works?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on one of symfony2.6 project. The purpose of this website is to load in other websites as a plugin.

```
{% javascripts 
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/intro.js'
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/enscroll.js'
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/select2.min.js'
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/pageguide.min.js'

 filter='uglifyjs2' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I have used assetic bundle load load js and css. This website is opened as in a popup. So this is where the problem occurs. the js and css takes that third party website's base url. SO I don't know how this base url parts works.

Comment: The question in the title, doesn't seem to match the body of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `asset_url` display an url like `src="/js/path/to/lib.js"` and you seems to need an absolute path.

You can use

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}
```

or

```
{{ app.request.getBaseURL() }}
```

Like that

```
{% javascripts 
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/intro.js'
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/enscroll.js'
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/select2.min.js'
'@OfficeBrainImagePersonalizeBundle/Resources/public/js/pageguide.min.js'

 filter='uglifyjs2' %}
    <script src="{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: This is working but problem is it's working on live sites who have using my service. When it comes to local, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm providing a tool that would be open in a pop up. It's like a image editor.

Comment: Hey @goto any idea about this? Your solution works but I'm wondering why it's working on live sites.

Comment: I don't really understand, what are the url of your assets in local and in live sites?

Comment: Sorry I was little bit confused. Thanks a lot. Your solution is working.